# Converting cs5 flash files to cs4

Tags: flash-cs5, flash-cs4

I have a .fla file in cs5 and on my laptop i have cs4. So i need to know if there is a way to turn my cs5 file into a cs4 file.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "save as type" option to save the file from Flash CS5 and have it be Flash CS4 compatible.

File > Save As > [Choose Flash CS4 Document from the Format Dropdown]

Comment: I can't believe I did't see that